# How can Python code within html string be evaluated?

Tags: python, html, string-formatting

I'm trying to create an HTML file, which certains Python variables that have to be evaluated. My code looks like this:

```
name = ['Nora', 'John', 'Jack', 'Jessica']

html = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Names</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>Mother: <%= name[0] %></li>
        <li>Father: <%= name[1] %></li>
        <li>Son: <%= name[2] %></li>
        <li>Daughter: <%= name[3] %></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
"""

Html_file = open("names.html","w")
Html_file.write(html)
Html_file.close()
```

However, the array is not interpreted during output. My HTML source looks like this:

```
...
<ul>
    <li>Mother: <%= name[0] %></li>
    <li>Father: <%= name[1] %></li>
    <li>Son: <%= name[2] %></li>
    <li>Daughter: <%= name[3] %></li>
</ul>
...
```

How can I evaluate the python code that's surrounded by `<%= %>`?

Comment: You're building a static string `html` but you're never combining this with your array `names`.  There are several ways to do this, search for `string formatting`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*There're multiple ways of achieving this*

First off, if you're on **Python 3.6 or higher**, there's a new syntax called [f-string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43123408/6622817), which is basically a method of string formatting at run time.

```
name = ['Nora', 'John', 'Jack', 'Jessica']

html = f"""
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Names</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>Mother: {name[0]}</li>
        <li>Father: {name[1]}</li>
        <li>Son: {name[2]}</li>
        <li>Daughter: {name[3]}</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
"""

print(html)
```

The way you use f-string is fairly easy, add an `f` in the beginning of the string, and use `{
}` instead of `<%= %>`.

---

If you're on **any Python version**, or wanted a version-compatible method, there are many other ways of [string interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) (ie. C-style string formatting `%`, Python string formatting `.format()`, and string concatenation), one of which (`.format()`) is in the other answers.

---

## Without changing your HTML: using `re` and `eval`

If you don't have control over where you got the "need-to-be-substituted" html, or if you *have to* use the `<%= %>` scheme, you can simply use a combination of `re` and `eval`:

```
from re import sub


name = ['Nora', 'John', 'Jack', 'Jessica']

html = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Names</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>Mother: <%= name[0] %></li>
        <li>Father: <%= name[1] %></li>
        <li>Son: <%= name[2] %></li>
        <li>Daughter: <%= name[3] %></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
"""

html = sub(r"<%=\s*(\S+)\s*%>", lambda l: eval(l.group(1)), html)

print(html)
```

Comment: The **f-string** is perfect for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
    html = """<ul>
        <li>Mother:  {0} </li>
        <li>Father:  {1} </li>
        <li>Son: {2} </li>
        <li>Daughter: {3} </li>
        </ul>"""
    name = ['Nora', 'John', 'Jack', 'Jessica']
    print(html.format(*name))
    >>><ul>
        <li>Mother: Nora </li>
        <li>Father: John </li>
        <li>Son: Jack </li>
        <li>Daughter: Jessica </li>
       </ul>
```

Comment: I don't think he wants the `<%=` and `%>` to appear in the html.

Comment: @Constance you're right.. I have edited my answer. thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

A string won't automatically evaluate code inside, but you can achieve this in a handful of ways:

Introduce placeholders and format your string:

```
name = ['Nora', 'John', 'Jack', 'Jessica']

html = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Names</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>Mother: {0}</li>
        <li>Father: {1}</li>
        <li>Son: {2}</li>
        <li>Daughter: {3}</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
"""

Html_file = open("names.html","w")
Html_file.write(html.format(name[0], name[1], name[2], name[3])
Html_file.close()
```

This is a very simple way to do it. There are more advanced approaches, such as using a template engine. [Here](https://www.fullstackpython.com/template-engines.html) you can read more about them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to more accurately evaluate the templating:

```
import re
name = ['Nora', 'John', 'Jack', 'Jessica']
def render_template(html, **kwargs):
  return re.sub('\<%\=\s[a-zA-Z]+\[\d+\]\s%\>', '{}', html).format(*[kwargs.get(re.findall('[a-zA-Z]+', i)[0])[int(re.findall('\d+', i)[0])] for i in re.findall('(?<=\<%\=\s)[a-zA-Z]+\[\d+\](?=\s%)', html)])

print(render_template(html, name = name))
```

Output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Names</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    <li>Mother: Nora</li>
    <li>Father: John</li>
    <li>Son: Jack</li>
    <li>Daughter: Jessica</li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

This solution will also work if `name` elements are being accessed in random order:

```
html = """
<body>
  <ul>
    <li>Mother: <%= name[3] %></li>
    <li>Father: <%= name[1] %></li>
    <li>Son: <%= name[0] %></li>
    <li>Daughter: <%= name[2] %></li>
 </ul>
</body>
"""
print(render_template(html, name = name))
```

Output:

```
<body>
  <ul>
   <li>Mother: Jessica</li>
   <li>Father: John</li>
   <li>Son: Nora</li>
   <li>Daughter: Jack</li>
</ul>
</body>
```