# Syntax Error even though there shouldn't be a Syntax Error (.configure())

Tags: python

I'm making a Tkinter GUI, and I want a button in it and if you click it there is a label under it and it will display how many times you've clicked. But it tells me there is a Syntax Error but I don't seem to find it.

I've tried to change the " to ' and so on but nothing works!!

```
def KlickCounter():
    Klicks = Klicks + 1
    Counter.configure(text='You have clicked the button ' + Klicks ' times')
```

I expect the Label to display the number "Klicks" which is the number of how many times you've clicked the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are simply missing another + after `Klicks` in your Counter.configure call :)

Comment: Python is also strongly typed: can't append an integer to a string. And, where is `Klicks` defined?

Answer (score 0):

As [@OsmosisJonesLoL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11306214/osmosisjoneslol) mentioned in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55500679/6282576), simply replace

```
Counter.configure(text='You have clicked the button ' + Klicks ' times')
```

with

```
Counter.configure(text='You have clicked the button ' + Klicks + ' times')
```

By adding `+` right after `Kicks`.

However, I wanted to suggest:
Avoid using `+` in order to concatenate strings. You can do it much better like this:

```
Counter.configure(text='You have clicked the button {} times'.format(Klicks))
```

Or, even [better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43123579/6282576), if you have **python 3.6 or above**, you can do it like this:

```
Counter.configure(text=f'You have clicked the button {Klicks} times')
```