# Python code for creating clickable link throwing error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am using Python 3 and below is my code which I am using to create clickable links once the data is returned from the data frame.

```
 #Create Clickable Link Value

df_linky = df_sorted
df_linky['Thread'] = df_sorted['Title'] + '#&#' + df_sorted['Link']
def make_clickable_both(val): 
    name, url = val.split('#&#')
    return f'<a href="{url}">{name}</a>'
df_compl = df_linky[['Thread','Score','Date Posted','Time Posted','Brand']]
df_complete = df_compl.reset_index(drop = True).set_index('Score')
df_complete = df_complete.style.format({'Thread': make_clickable_both})
return df_complete
```

I am getting an error in terminal

```
    return f'<a href="{url}">{name}</a>'
                                       ^
   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

And in the return value

```
429 {name}  2019-05-16  03:11   Smart Water
```

At the place of "{name}" it should be the name of the link, can any one suggest what is going wrong with this, I am using pandas library.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Sorry I just updated the question

Comment: Looks like your Python version doesn't support f-strings

Comment: It is python 3 ?

Comment: Not all versions of Python 3 support them, so you should update

Comment: f-strings are supported in Python versions 3.6 and above.

Comment: So what is the other solution for this?

Comment: Use other types of formatting: `'<a href="%s">%s</a>' % (url, name)` or `'<a href="{}">{}</a>'.format(url, name)`.

Comment: Awesome  return '<a href="{}">{}</a>'.format(url, name) did the trick superb thank you. You can submit your answer I will approve it

Comment: A link to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/string.html#formatspec) of the format specification language is my answer :P

Comment: It is for the first time I was using Python for html conversion Lol My python usage was specific only to Server side and deployment scripts

Comment: Hi, is your problem solved?

Answer (score 2):

You're using "[f-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43123408/f-strings-in-python-3-6)," which was introduced in `Python 3.6`.

You can either update your Python version to 3.6, or you can do it like this:

```
return '<a href="{}">{}</a>'.format(url, name)
```

You need `Python 2.6` or above for this to work.

Or you can use this "[Old-school](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)" formatting that "has been in the language since the very beginning."

```
return '<a href="%s">%s</a>' % (url, name)
```