# Why are f-strings faster than str() to parse values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-internals, f-string

I was playing around with f-strings (see [PEP 498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)), and I decided to check the speed of the f-string parse, (e.g. `f"{1}"`) in comparison with the usual str parse (e.g `str(1)`). But to my surprise, when I checked the speed of both methods with the [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.timeit) function, I found out
that f-strings are faster.

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit("f'{1}'")
0.1678762999999961
```

whereas

```
>>> timeit("str(1)")
0.3216999999999999
```

or even the repr func, which in most of the cases is faster than str cast

```
>>> timeit("repr(1)")
0.2528296999999995
```

I wonder why is that? I thought that the f-strings called str internally, but now, I'm a bit confused, any ideas? Thanks in advance!

PD: Just if anyone is wondering:

```
assert f"{1}" == str(1) == repr(1)
```

Comment: It's similar to why [] is faster than list().

Comment: Related: [f-strings vs str.format()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43123408/4518341)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The simple answer is because [**f-strings are part of the language's grammar and syntax.**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) The `str()` call on the other hand requires a symbol table lookup, followed by a function call.

Here's a similar example which interpolates an integer variable, contrast this with the constant value interpolation.

```
x = 1

%timeit f'{1}'
%timeit f'{x}'
%timeit str(1)
%timeit str(x)

113 ns ± 2.25 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
166 ns ± 4.71 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
342 ns ± 23.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
375 ns ± 11.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

---

The difference in the behaviour is obvious when you look at the disassembled byte code with **[`dis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#dis.Bytecode.dis)**.

```
import dis

dis.dis("f'{x}'")
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (x)
              2 FORMAT_VALUE             0
              4 RETURN_VALUE

dis.dis("str(x)")
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (str)
              2 LOAD_NAME                1 (x)
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

The heavy lifting is all in the `CALL_FUNCTION` instruction, an overhead which f-strings certainly don't have -- at least in this case, as nothing needs to be `eval`'d.