# concatenate two element of different list as 1 variable in python

Tags: python, list, concatenation

concatenate two elements as 1 element
for example we are given two arrays a and b:

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=[4,5,6]
```

so what I want is an output as

```
14, 25, 36
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `list(10*aa + bb for aa, bb in zip(a, b))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `a` and `b` are lists of integers, you could do the following:

```
c = [i * 10 + j for i, j in zip(a, b)]
```

If they are lists of strings, you could do the following:

```
c = [i + j for i, j in zip(a, b)]
```

Comment: `map(lambda t: t[0]*10+t[1], zip(a,b))`

Comment: You wouldn't need `zip`: `map(lambda x, y: x*10 + y, a, b)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
result = [int(f'{x}{y}') for x, y in zip(a, b)]
```

Comment: For the given input, this is considerably slower than doing the math.

Comment: Yeah, doing math is more optimized than this ;)

Comment: For a slight improvement: `int(f'{x}{y}')` is likely faster that str concat. (ref: [Why are f-strings faster than str() to parse values?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56587807/15497888))