# how to shuffle a deck of cards in python

Tags: python-3.x

M code works however I want it to use Ace Jack Queen and King instead of 1, 11,12,13 however I dont know how to change my code so it will do it.

```
# imports random
import itertools, random

# make a deck of cards
deck = list(itertools.product(range(1, 14), ['Spade', 'Heart', 
'Diamond', 'Club']))

# shuffles the deck
random.shuffle(deck)

# draw five cards
howmany = int(input('How many cards do you want to display? '))
print('You got:')
for i in range(howmany):
    print(deck[i][0], 'of', deck[i][1])
```

Current Results.

How many cards do you want to display? 4
    You got:
    11 of Diamond
    7 of Club
    6 of Diamond
    8 of Diamond

However I want it to output for the first one for example,

Jack of Diamond

Comment: Just replace `range(1, 14)` with `["Ace", "2", "3", ...]`?

Comment: replace range(1, 14) with ['Ace']+ list(range(2,11)) + ['jack','Queen','King']

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd do it. Notice that I changed the last bit of your code mostly. This is to provide a use-case of tuple unpacking, `get` [dictionary method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041405/why-dict-getkey-instead-of-dictkey) and [f-strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43123408/f-strings-in-python-3-6):

```py
# imports random
import itertools, random

# make a deck of cards
deck = list(itertools.product(range(1, 14), ['Spade', 'Heart', 
'Diamond', 'Club']))

# shuffles the deck
random.shuffle(deck)

# have a dict of named cards
cards = {11: "Jack", 12: "Queen", 13: "King", 1:"Ace"}

# draw five cards
howmany = int(input('How many cards do you want to display? '))
print('You got:')
for i in range(howmany):
    card, suit = deck[i] # unpack the tuple to have cleaner code
    print(f"{cards.get(card, card)} of {suit}") # use f-string together with get
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools, random

deck = list(itertools.product(['Ace']+ list(range(2,11)) + ['jack','Queen','King'] ,['Spade','Heart','Diamond','Club']))

random.shuffle(deck)

print("You got:")
for i in range(1):
   print(deck[i][0], "of", deck[i][1])
```

Comment: Please explain what this does and how it answers the question. Answers with code only are not epic.