# Should I use f-strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, f-string

These two `print` statements produce the same results and at least *to me* the first version looks more readable.

Should I stick with the `f'` version because it will cause issues for me later on or cause worse performance or does not follow the present Python standards? Or is it only a question of consistent usage of *one* of these versions?

```
print('My first bicycle was a ' + bicycles[1])
print(f'My first bicycle was a {bicycles[1]})')
```

Comment: I think ``print("My first bycicle was a{}".format(bicycles[1]))`` looks more readable.

Comment: If you need formatting, you should use `%`-formatting, `str.format` or f-string. First version is not helpful for that case. About performance, f-string is much faster.

Comment: f-strings are more readable, faster and allow to evaluate expressions in the placeholder. Definitely best approach.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43123408/f-strings-in-python-3-6

Comment: For example, `f'{a:.3f}'` cannot be (simply) performed by `+` concatenation.

Comment: f-strings are also useful as with variables other than strings, you don't have to explicitly convert them to a string representation to concatenate them...

Comment: If your first bicycle was `bicycles[1]`, whatever happened to `bicycles[0]`? ;)

Comment: You can do `bicycles = ["unicycle", "penny farthing"]; "bicycle is a {1}".format(*bicycles)` instead.

Comment: I don't find f-strings more readable, and when using many interpolated variables the `format` approach of supplying a single `dict` and then naming the interpolations works well: `args = {"one":1, "two":2, "three":"shoe"}; "{one}, {two} buckle my {three}".format(**args)`

Comment: There may be places that f-strings can reduce lines into a more compact (more complex) expression but this is not Pythonic and given the clarity of `format` is over-reach. What is faintly ridiculous is when the top 2 advantages of f-strings are "readability" (I find `format` more readable) and things like: "A key advantage of Python f-strings is the ability to execute expressions at runtime". Did anyone notice Python was already doing this before f-strings came along? So now it's an advantage to move Python statements inside strings, like PHP? F-strings don't add value and are an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 5):

From [PEP 498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/), a PEP (Python Enhancement Proposals) dedicated to Literal String Interpolation,

> F-strings provide a way to embed expressions inside string literals,
> using a minimal syntax. **It should be noted that an f-string is really**
> **an expression evaluated at run time, not a constant value**. In Python
> source code, an f-string is a literal string, prefixed with ‘f’, which
> contains expressions inside braces. The expressions are replaced with
> their values.

The main point here is the highlighted text. That means it is way better in evaluation due to the internal implementation of [ASTs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) (abstract syntax trees) by the [CPython](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPython) compiler which makes them fast.

Also, I think it is more readable and in case of more variables in your string it provides better readability. Multi-line string interpolation can be performed easily using this syntax.

For example,

```
f'''
    My first bicycle was a {bicycles[0]}
    It has color {bicycles[0]["color"]}
    and has {bicycles[0]["gears"]} gears.
'''
```

Comment: I don't understand how the quoted text supports your statement "it is way better in evaluation due to internal implementation of AST(Abstract syntax trees) by CPython compiler which makes them fast." In fact, I don't understand that sentence at all, and doubt it is true.

Comment: Under the hood, the `f-string` processing is divided into the evaluation of values within brackets and their placement with the rest of the constant string component. For a complex `f-string`, ASTs play a vital role in the faster evaluation. To see how the AST is created, you could use the `ast` library `ast.dump(ast.parse('''f"Sum: {a + b}"'''))`.  To dive deeper and understand the speed comparison of `f-string` vs `str.format()` vs `%-formatting` you need to look at the disassembled byte code which could be produced using the `dis` library. @JW.

Comment: Why didn't they just re-implement a faster `format`?

Comment: @NeilG Actually, there are ongoing efforts to do that :) https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/72495

Comment: I'm glad there is commitment to `format` @VishnudevKrishnadas - perhaps one day f-strings can be depreciated.

Comment: According to PEP, they do not intend on deprecating any existing string formatting mechanisms. Check [this](https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/#:~:text=This%20PEP%20does%20not%20propose%20to%20remove%20or%20deprecate%20any%20of%20the%20existing%20string%20formatting%20mechanisms.). Also, I am for `f-strings` as they are much more readable although `format` is better in some cases. @NeilG

Comment: @VishnudevKrishnadas, when people say "f-strings are more readable" they usually, as you have, make a blunt assertion as if they measured them on a numeric scale. Of course it's subjective, but reasons could be described why f-strings are supposedly more readable, but I've never seen that attempted. I find the methods similar. In some cases f-strings get really diabolical, especially when execution is moved inside the string. I'd be interested to get a justification for your statement. The differences in readability are slight and not always in f-strings' favour.

Comment: As mentioned in my previous comment, *"I am for f-strings as they are much more readable"*, notice the words "I am". This means it is just a personal opinion based on experience and not a generalized one. I have had to work with strings where it mostly was for variable interpolation and not execution inside the string. My second statement states *"although format is better in some cases"*, which in your case is more relevant.

Comment: Another opinion by experience: You can make f-strings more readable by moving the compute outside to a variable with a readable name. There is always a tradeoff between readability and compute time. In this case, I favor readability following [Zen of Python](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/#the-zen-of-python). Example: `area_of_circle = pi * (r ** 2)` and `print(f'Geometrical Measurement of Figure: {area_of_circle}')` ✅ over `print(f'Geometrical Measurement of Figure: {pi * (r ** 2)}')` ❌. @NeilG

Comment: Yeah that's so funny @VishnudevKrishnadas. The core un-feature that f-strings bring in is also the core problem with it. And even that un-feature reduces readability. But people still quote readability as an advantage of f-strings. What a catastrophe. Back to the future with performant `str.format` please. `"Geometrical Measurement of Figure: {area_of_circle}".format(**args)`

Comment: Can you explain why it is funny? I'm here to learn. Please enlighten me why `format` is superior? I would then apply it to my daily work. Also, what do you mean by un-feature? @NeilG

Comment: I don't think our conversation is appropriate here any longer @VishnudevKrishnadas and I think you're too clever to be so deliberately obtuse, I'm surprised you claim not to see the circularity. f-strings interpolate expressions inside strings instead of using `str.format`. This makes them "more readable" (primary quoted benefit of f-strings). But in order to make this new f-string approach more readable, move your expression outside the string again. Now you're good.  I also think you could guess "un-feature" if you tried. f-strings encourage anti-patterns with little if any added value.

Comment: Point taken on the f-strings – they're a bit like chili in cooking, aren't they? A dash enhances flavor, but too much overwhelms the dish. Let's 'un-feature' this discussion and leave it for the community to decide. Thanks for stirring up the pot and sharing you knowledge! @NeilG