# difference between two ways of printing a colored text

Tags: python

I want to print a colored text in console. So I use this code provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/287944):

```
class bcolors:
    HEADER = '\033[95m'
    OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
    OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
    WARNING = '\033[93m'
    FAIL = '\033[91m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'
```

I'm hesitant about the way we can use this class. It has been said that:

> To use code like this, you can do something like
>
> print(bcolors.WARNING + "Warning: No active frommets remain.
>   Continue?" + bcolors.ENDC)
>
> or, with Python3.6+:
>
> print(f"{bcolors.WARNING}Warning: No active frommets remain.
>   Continue?{bcolors.ENDC}")

I'm using python 3.7, but both of these codes work for me, so I wanted to know how the usage is different based on Python version and what is that `f` mentioned `Python3.6+` part?

Comment: The first example is using string concatenation which is available in all versions of python. The second one uses f-strings which were introduced in python 3.6. They are a "nicer" way of doing the same thing.

Comment: BTW: you can also use `"{}Warning: No active frommets remain. Continue?{}".format(bcolors.WARNING, bcolors.ENDC)`. There is also old method with `%` - see more: https://pyformat.info/

Comment: I don't see what that question has to do with colored text... Your question is basically what is `f`-strings? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43123408/f-strings-in-python-3-6

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking, the f-strings are faster. So you should consider using them if performance matters.
See “Python f-strings: fun strings, fast strings” by Gus Goulart https://link.medium.com/l54akhN0y6