# How to set a name of creating file from variable?

Tags: python

I need to create a file with the name provided by the user as input. For example, If the user-provided value `hello` then the file name should be `hello.txt` , here is a sample code to create a new file.

```
import os
recipeFileName = input()
currentRecipe = open("fileName.txt", "x")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [f-strings vs str.format()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43123408/f-strings-vs-str-format)

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a text file so pls use `w` instead of `x`.

```
recipeFileName = input("Input file Name: ")
currentRecipe = open( recipeFileName + '.txt' , "w")
# insert into file
currentRecipe.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

`open` can be used to create a file.(you can just replace the string "fileName.txt" with the veriable containing the string and add '.txt' for the extension

```py
recipeFileName = input()
currentRecipe = open(recipeFileName+'.txt' , "x")
```