# Need assistance counting letters in input

Tags: python, count

I have this code:

```
def main():
    test_str = input('Enter word')

    def count_dict(mystring):
        d = {}
        for w in mystring:
            d[w] = mystring.count(w)

        for k in sorted(d):
            print(k + ' : ' + str(d[k]))

    mystring = test_str
    count_dict(mystring)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and my output is like this:

```
Enter word: test
Output:
e : 1
s : 1
t : 2
```

Now the question is how can I add a `'` to make it look like this:

```
'e' : 1
's' : 1
't' : 2
```

Comment: Are you asking how to escape quotes? `print('\'')`

Comment: Not sure, i think it has something to do with my print(k + ' : ' + str(d[k])) 
I need to somehow add "  '  " to before and after the e, s and t like shown in the post.

Comment: Just `print("'" + k "'" + ' : ' + str(d[k]))` or what?

Comment: Haha yes that works! Thanks a lot, i tried  ' ' ' but that didnt work. Didnt even think to use " ' "

Comment: Print the `repr(k)` instead of `k`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my approach: (Diffs. are commented)
[more about f-strings vs string-format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43123408/f-strings-vs-str-format)

```
def main():
    test_str = input('Enter word: ')  # slightly changed representation

    def count_dict(mystring):
        
        d = {}
        for w in mystring:
            d[w] = mystring.count(w)

        for k in sorted(d):
            print(f'("{k}" : {str(d[k])})')  # you may check out python f-strings

    mystring = test_str
    count_dict(mystring)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```