# saving the outputs of a python based for loop to separate text file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, for-loop

i have a .mat file.I want to read its each column and want to save each column to separate text file like data_1.txt data_2.txt....data_10.txt

My script is

```
import numpy as np
import h5py


c1 = h5py.File('test_data.mat', 'r')  
out1=c1.get('dat')


for x in range(10):
   dd=out1[x]
   np.savetxt('data_x.txt', dd,fmt='%10.2f')
```

But it doesnot write  to separate text file, can anybody suggest a better solution for the same. Thanks.

Comment: You're writing to the same file named 'data_x.txt'. Try `f'data_{x}.txt'`, a name that changes with each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

you're close - change the filename by including the index in it

```py
...
    np.savetxt(f"data_{x}.txt", dd,fmt='%10.2f')
```

the change is subtle: this uses an [f-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43123408/f-strings-vs-str-format), which allows you to easily write variables into a string by-name