# How could I implement “HH:MM:SS” format

Tags: python

I am asked to do this:

Write a program that adds one second to a clock time, given its hours, minutes and seconds.

Input consists of three natural numbers h, m and s that represent a clock time, that is, such that h<24, m<60 and s<60.

This is the code I came up with:

```
from easyinput import read
    h = read(int)
    m = read(int)
    s = read(int)
    
    seconds = (s+1)%60
    minutes = (m + (s+1)//60)%60
    hours = h + (m + (s+1)//60))//60

    print(hours, minutes, seconds)
```

It does its function well, if I have

```
13 59 59
```

it returns

```
14 0 0
```

I am sure it could be bettered, but that's not the problem right now.

The problem is that I need the format to be like this:

```
11:33:16
```

It should be “HH:MM:SS”, and I don't know how to do it.
Anyone could help me?? Thanksss :)))

Comment: Does this answer your question? [f-strings vs str.format()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43123408/f-strings-vs-str-format)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an f-string with format modifiers. `02d` says "an int with field width `2` padded with `0`."

```
print(f"{hours:02d}:{minutes:02d}:{seconds:02d}")
```

```
>>> hours = 13
>>> minutes = 3
>>> seconds = 5
>>> print(f"{hours:02d}:{minutes:02d}:{seconds:02d}")
13:03:05
>>>
```

Note that the `d` in the format specifiers is unnecessary. You could write:

```
print(f"{hours:02}:{minutes:02}:{seconds:02}")
```

[Documentation on f-strings.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

Answer (score 2):

Usually, you don't want to deal with calculating date and time yourself, so a better approach is to use the [native library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) that works with date and time out of the box:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from easyinput import read

h, m, s = read(int), read(int), read(int)

time = datetime.now().replace(hour=h, minute=m, second=s)
time += timedelta(seconds=1)

print(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print(f'{hours:>02}:{minutes:>02}:{seconds:>02}')
```

Comment: Not incorrect but would be improved with explanation/elaboration.